# UI tools for Ruby testing framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rubygems, ruby-test

Is there a UI for Ruby's testing framework similar to JUnit's UI that's built into Eclipse or MSUnit built into Visual Studio? However, I am not particularly interested in an IDE integration. It could be a standalone application, most likely web. This should have the basic functionality of all unit-testing tools:

1. List all tests within the project
2. List all tests within a given file in the project
3. Be able to run a group of tests or a single test and get feedback

Comment: look at http://seleniumhq.org/

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with JUnit, but you could integrate something like [simplecov](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov) for coverage results for your tests.

You can also use a CI server like [Jenkins CI](http://jenkins-ci.org/) or [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/)

These tools should cover all of the requirements you list when used in tandem with a testing framework.

Answer (score 0):

[RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/features/ruby_unit_testing.html) has a graphical test runner. It obviously costs money(unless you are doing [open-source](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/buy/buy.jsp#openSource)) and it comes with a complete IDE, which may not be what you want. It is the only graphical test runner for ruby that I have heard of.

Have you considered rolling your own? You might be able to get the basics working pretty easily.